# startActivity(intent) shows an error when calling a number in Fragment upon Button click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I need to call a number upon clicking an `ImageButton` in my custom `ListView` in my `Fragment`. I have given

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +rowItem.getPhone()));
startActivity(intent);
```

But there is an error showing like this in eclipse:

> The method `startActivity(Intent)` is undefined for the type new `View.OnClickListener(){}`

Here in my app, this is not an activity where as it is a fragment, since I'm using navigation drawer. So the `startactivity(intent)` won't work in fragment. How can this be made working in fragment? I have given the proper permissions in my Android Manifest also. So there is no problem of permission in my app.

Here are the contents of my entire class **CustomListViewAdapter** which is shown below:

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem>{

    Typeface tf;
    Context context;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
            List<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView name;
        TextView designation;
        TextView phonenumber;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        ImageButton call,sms;
        final RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"MLKR0NTT.TTF");

            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.designation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.phonenumber=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.name.setText(rowItem.getName());
        holder.designation.setText(rowItem.getDesignation());
        holder.name.setTypeface(tf);
        holder.designation.setTypeface(tf);
        holder.phonenumber.setText(rowItem.getPhone());
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(rowItem.getImage());
        call=(ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.callbutton);
        call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Calling "+rowItem.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +rowItem.getPhone()));

                // Here I need to start the activity for calling the number which is obtained using rowItem.getPhone(). 
                //But the method startActivity(intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try calling it with the context ? Like this context.startActivity(your intent object);

Comment: Yes.. But the app force closes. And the log is showing like this:

android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this....

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Not working. Using this causes the app to force close. And the log is showing like this: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want? –

Comment: @TeeJay please check the updated answer...if it's not working can you show how you are setting adapter for view in activity

Comment: Is there any way to show the toast in my font ie. in malayalam font. Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Calling "+rowItem.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

rowItem.getName() gives name in malayalam, which is in utf-8 format. When I toast it in my app, instead of displaying in utf-8 it is showing in ascii as junk characters...

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it on a context.  If this is a subclass in the Activity, use `MyActivityName.this.startActivity()`.  If its in a Fragment, use `getActivity().startActivity()`.

Comment: `getActivity().startActivity()`  is also not available.. it is showing error in eclipse.

Comment: The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){} is showing in eclipse...

Comment: Then you're not in a Fragment either.  What is your top level class?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to call it from another class, the onClick listener.  You need to have a way to reference the enclosing class of the activity from within the onClick class.

First setup a field for the activity.

```
Activity activity;
```

Then in onCreate():

```
activity = this;
```

Finally in your onClick method of the listener:

```
activity.startActivity(intent)
```

Hope this helps,

George

Answer (score 0):

Just use the context variable .. since it was been passed from the activity/fragment where you
call your adapter..

```
    context.startActivity(intent);
```